# how to pass input of a text box as title in another form

Tags: c#

I need to enter Name and Surname in a text box then press a button to take me to another form and that form should have the Name and Surname as form title.

So far I have this code:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nameandSurname = txtNameandSurname.Text;
        string username = txtUsername.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;

        if (username == "designer" && password == "123")
        {
            Design_Form frm = new Design_Form();
            frm.Show();
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is incorrect.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
frm.Text = txtNameandSurname.Text
```

Write it just before `frm.Show()`.

Comment: Is that a parameter? because I need to use a parameter.

Comment: No just tick my post. It will show green right tick which will give me 10 points

Comment: No I mean the answer that you gave me?

Comment: Choice is all yours Mr. User3177361